# Does the new Taliban government in Afghanistan still not recognize the Duran line? Do they propose any other well-defined border with Pakistan?

Tags: government, pakistan, borders, afghanistan, taliban

[This answer to *Have cross-border terrorist attacks in Pakistan declined or stayed the same after the Taliban takeover of Afghanistan?*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/69568/16047) mentions the [Duran line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durand_Line) and the Afghanistan's government lack of recognition of it, and the complexities involved.

The answer is now almost six months old, and the new Taliban-led government is grappling with several major issues related to establishing/reworking a large country's new government.

So I'd like to ask:

> Does the new Taliban government in Afghanistan still not recognize the Duran line? Do they propose any other well-defined border with Pakistan?

If there is no border with Pakistan that they recognize or propose, then one might wonder what their long term plans are<sup>1</sup>.

Wikipedia's [Government of the Islamic Emirate of Afghanistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_of_the_Islamic_Emirate_of_Afghanistan) currently includes only two instances of the word "border"

1. that the government has a "Border Commission" on its leadership council
2. That [Noorullah Noori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noorullah_Noori) is the current *acting* [Minister of the Borders and Tribal Affairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministry_of_Borders_and_Tribal_Affairs) although that article says that it's instead [Gul Zarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gul_Zarin) although I do not know if this ministry is only in charge of *internal borders* related to local governments and tribal affairs, or if it also covers the national borders.

---

Potentially related:

- <sup>1</sup>https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/54266/16047

Comment: Upvoted, but peacefully solving border disputes often takes years if not decades of negotiations. I can't imagine Afghanistan managing it faster, for some reason. Pakistan's economy is not doing so well at the moment (they had to resort to IMF again) so I can't imagine them having much carrots they can dangle to Afghanistan at the moment. Ironically, they had more leverage over the Taliban while the latter were not in power.